# Where to setup email id on all contact form in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, forms, email, contacts, ninja

I have a question related to WordPress...I have installed the WordPress theme on this domain www.digitalmarkito.com and import demo data too for the look and feel so that I can update my data.

In this theme, there is Ninja Form and E&P Form builder plugin installed as a contact form, request a quote form, services form, etc...and I was testing the all contact form(updated my email id on all contact form) that emails are going where after submitting the form and I was expecting that I have updated my email id on all contact form then I will get email after submission but I did not get an email through contact form after submission.

This is the issue, How, I will set up my email id on all form so that I can get an email after submitting the form.

Help will be appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Looking forward to the positive answer from you guys!.

Thanks

Comment: Install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-test-email/ & check, are you receiving emails? If not you need to configure your SMTP client (on erver)

Comment: Thank you Earid, I have configured SMTP and it works.

Answer (score 0):

All of the mails are send to the admin.Check your Administration Email Address you can replace it with email id on which you want to send the mails.